# Silverlight Socket Constantly Returns With Empty Buffer

Tags: silverlight, sockets

I am using Silverlight to interact with a proxy application that I have developed but, without the proxy sending a message to the Silverlight application, it executes the receive completed handler with an empty buffer ('\0's).  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  It is causing a **major** memory leak.

```
this._rawBuffer = new Byte[this.BUFFER_SIZE];
SocketAsyncEventArgs receiveArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
receiveArgs.SetBuffer(_rawBuffer, 0, _rawBuffer.Length);
receiveArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(ReceiveComplete);
this._client.ReceiveAsync(receiveArgs);
```

---

```
if (args.SocketError == SocketError.Success && args.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Receive)
{
    // Read the current bytes from the stream buffer
    int bytesRecieved = this._client.ReceiveBufferSize;
    // If there are bytes to process else the connection is lost
    if (bytesRecieved > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            //Find out what we just received
            string messagePart = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_rawBuffer, 0, _rawBuffer.GetLength(0));
            //Take out any trailing empty characters from the message
            messagePart = messagePart.Replace('\0'.ToString(), "");
            //Concatenate our current message with any leftovers from previous receipts
            string fullMessage = _theRest + messagePart;
            int seperator;

            //While the index of the seperator (LINE_END defined & initiated as private member)
            while ((seperator = fullMessage.IndexOf((char)Messages.MessageSeperator.Terminator)) > 0)
            {
                //Pull out the first message available (up to the seperator index
                string message = fullMessage.Substring(0, seperator);
                //Queue up our new message
                _messageQueue.Enqueue(message);
                //Take out our line end character
                fullMessage = fullMessage.Remove(0, seperator + 1);
            }

            //Save whatever was NOT a full message to the private variable used to store the rest
            _theRest = fullMessage;

            //Empty the queue of messages if there are any
            while (this._messageQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        // Wait for a new message

        if (this._isClosing != true)
            Receive();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the second block of code is your `ReceiveComplete` handler. If so, you should be looking at the [SocketAsyncEventArgs.BytesTransferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.bytestransferred(VS.95).aspx) property to get the count of the bytes received.

Comment: Thank you!!  Simple mistakes at their finest!